# Publishing a map service with Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I want to share offline my data on my ArcGIS Online account using Python. I found this as a result of my research.(https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/publish-map-services/publishing-a-map-service-with-python.htm).I get this error while doing the first step (ie CreateMap Draft example 1). But will this fix the problem for offline publishing?[image]

Comment: Please do not repost closed questions. Instead, Edit them to address the highlighted/commented defect(s) and vote to reopen [How can I publish the map service to my ArcGIS Online account with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387608/how-can-i-publish-the-map-service-to-my-arcgis-online-account-with-python)

Comment: Please don't post text as an image. It makes it hard to read, impossible to copy, and impossible to find in search.